# How to handle very deep recursive call in game example

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following code solving a toy problem by recursion:

```py
import math
import sys

def b_step(n):
    if n > 2:
        return a_step(math.floor(n+1)/2) or a_step(n-1)
    return True

def a_step(n):
    if n > 2:
        return b_step(math.floor((n+1)/2)) and b_step(n-1)
    return False

print(a_step(1000000000000))
```

The problem is: A and B are taking turns playing a game of replacing a number `n` of tokens with either `floor((n+1)/2)` or `n-1`. The player who can make a single token be left wins. The function `a_step(n)` should return `True` if B can possibly win the game (unregarded of which turns A takes).

My implementation seems to work, but unfortunately it takes forever to terminate on very large `n`. Does someone have an idea to get a more performance implementation? I though about unrolling the recursion, but I don't think that's possible, since we have to calls in each method.

Update: The algorithm I am giving here is probably not even a valid solution to the problem.

Comment: This looks like something that can be simplified into a formula or a loop.  I'd avoid an implementation that involves recursion if your `n` can get large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fun fact, I tested your `a_step` function against first `100_000` numbers and I got the following numbers when your function returns `True`:

```
[(i, a_step(i)) for i in range(100000) if a_step(i)]
```

output:

```
[(3, True),
 (9, True),
 (19, True),
 (39, True),
 (79, True),
 (159, True),
 (319, True),
 (639, True),
 (1279, True),
 (2559, True),
 (5119, True),
 (10239, True),
 (20479, True),
 (40959, True),
 (81919, True)]
```

except the first element (3), all the other numbers behave like a progression where the nth term can be described by `a(n) = a(n-1) + (a(n-1) - a(n-2)) * 2`

```
a1, a2 = 9, 19

for index in range(3, 15):
    a1, a2 = a2, a2 + (a2 - a1) *2
    print(f'a{index} = {a2}')
```

**output:**

```
a3 = 39
a4 = 79
a5 = 159
a6 = 319
a7 = 639
a8 = 1279
a9 = 2559
a10 = 5119
a11 = 10239
a12 = 20479
a13 = 40959
a14 = 81919
```

Assuming that the progression formula can give you the next `True` (I didn't prove this):

- for `a_step(1000000000000)`, the answer will be `False` since `a(37)
  = 687194767359` and `a(38) = 1374389534719`

Comment: Awesome find. Unfortunately the automatic test I have given for the problem is saying the answer is wrong. This is probably not related to your solution, but to my algorithm.

Comment: The other answer is more fit for your question

Comment: Welcome! Another library, you mean `functools`?

Comment: Yes, I can't use `functools`

Comment: functools is a build in module in python and you do not need to install any other 3rd party library, it is included in python

Answer (score 1):

since your functions are using previous results you could use [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) from `functools`

```
import math
import sys
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(256)
def b_step(n):
    if n > 2:
        return a_step(math.floor(n+1)/2) or a_step(n-1)
    return True

@lru_cache(256)
def a_step(n):
    if n > 2:
        return b_step(math.floor((n+1)/2)) and b_step(n-1)
    return False

print(a_step(1_000_000_000_000))
```

**output:**

```
False
```

this approach is really fast, and it shows that for 687194767359 and 1374389534719 your function return `True` (related to the previous answer)